# how to remove multiple semicolons from this data below using pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to remove the multiple semi colons from this query data. i use trim but its not working full.

```
;ghulam.nabi@yahoo.com.pk;NOCBSS@yahoo.com.pk;;;fo.n2@yahoo.com.pk;;mumtaz.akhta@yahoo.com.pk
```

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

If you know how many semicolons do you want to change: `replace` function.

```
select 
replace(';ghulam.nabi@yahoo.com.pk;NOCBSS@yahoo.com.pk;;;fo.n2@yahoo.com.pk;;mumtaz.akhta@yahoo.com.pk',';;',';') S
from dual
```

**SQL Fiddle** [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13486/0)

If you want to change two or more semicolons: `REGEXP_REPLACE` function

```
select 
REGEXP_REPLACE(';ghulam.nabi@yahoo.com.pk;NOCBSS@yahoo.com.pk;;;fo.n2@yahoo.com.pk;;mumtaz.akhta@yahoo.com.pk','(;){2,}',';') as s
from dual
```

**SQL Fiddle** [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13484/0)

More information

- [Replace](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php)
- [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--REGEXP_REPLACE_882.htm)

Comment: brother i need 1 semi colon... i want to remove other than 1 semi colons

Comment: hahaha.. yeah i already voted bro :) and also accept the ans as well :)